# Handling listview item children click events and updates

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have activity which populates listview with customadpater. The Adapter inflates a layout which contains(buttons, textview,seekbar...)

I want the buttons click listeners, updating textview and seekbar thumb to be handled in actvity not inside the getView() method of adapter.

my activity and adapter are different classes. I need a employ a proper design here any help please.

Comment: Are you using a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: No, listveiw extending activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best design for implementing this is to do what was suggested by @Autocrab and the code to do this is like this:

```
public class ParentClass implements View.onClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        // MORE AND MORE AND MORE
    }

public class MyAdapter {

    onClickListener mListener;

    public MyAdapter (ParentClass activity, List<?> list) {
        mListener = (onClickListener)activity;
        // MORE AND MORE
    }

    public View getView(...) {
        lButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    }
}
```

the only problem with code like that is [cyclic refrencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) that should be avoided in all coast.

there for, you should probably use [WeakRefrences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

when using a `WeakReference` it's very important to check every time before getting it that it's not null, like this:

```
public class MyAdapter {

    WeakReference<OnClickListener> mListener;

    public MyAdapter (ParentClass activity, List<?> list) {
        mListener = new WeakReference<OnClickListener>(onClickListener)activity;
        // MORE AND MORE
    }

    public View getView(...) {
        lButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mListener.get() != null) {
                    mListener.get().preformClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any example of WeakReferences

Comment: where does the '(onClickListener)' come from. while construct the mListener.

Comment: still not clear, could you please udpate your second code snippet.

Comment: Lint flag as **OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: dude! you should think a bit by yourself. I might have got some spelling errors, and no imports. try it yourself

Comment: okay, that needed proper import  and one more thing performClick is defined in View. how could it be possible to access from OnClickListener object.?

Answer (score 0):

implement interfaces for button (onclick), seekbar (onprogress) in your activity.
Then pass these interfaces to the adapter's constructor. in method `getView()` assign these listeners to views.

Comment: could you please explain  'in method getView() assign these listeners to views.' any code snippets